# A* star openlist is not working as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path-finding, a-star

I was once asking about a datastructure for A*. I solved this issue now. But there is another problem. My A* is slow and not working as I expect it. That means 
I implemented the source code in Java from the Wikipedia Pseudocodes (German and English). The graph below in the image is the graph I used for test purposes. The algorithm is starting from node 1 to the destination node 8 for example. The heuristic function will be calculated by using the Manhattan distance using the coordinates in square brakes next to the node. The closedlist is build from start node 1(predecessor) to 3(1)-6(3)-2(1)-4(1)-3(2)-2(3)-4(3)-8(6). I thought the A* is going from 1 to 8 directly, because it is the shortest path. But it jumps from 6 back to node 2, because the f value of 2 is the lowest in the list. So is this correct? In examples I have seen it never jumps to any other node back, after it visited a node afterwards. I have a graph which is connected from both directions with the other nodes. Therefore I changed the if conditions in the source code to proof if the reverse way is or is not in the corresponding list. Otherwise it would end in an endless loop.
What is the problem and why is it jumping from node 6 back to node 2? Do I have to delete the nodes in my openlist?
[image].

```
public ArrayList<NodeD> executeAstar(ArrayList<Arclistentry> data, NodeD start, NodeD dest)
{
    openlist = new PriorityQueue<NodeD>(1,comp);
    closedlist.clear();
    openlist.offer(start);
    start.setg(0);
    start.seth( manhattendistance(start, dest));
    start.setf(start.getg()+start.geth());
    while(!openlist.isEmpty())
    {
        NodeD currentnode = openlist.poll();
        if(currentnode.getnodenumber() == dest.getpredessor())
        {
            closedlist.add(currentnode);
            return closedlist;
        }
        closedlist.add(currentnode);
        for(int i=0; i< data.size(); i++)
        {
            if(data.get(i).getstart()==currentnode.getnodenumber())
            {
                NodeD successor = new NodeD(data.get(i).getnode(),data.get(i).getstart(), data.get(i).getcoorddest());
                NodeD reversesuccessor = new NodeD(data.get(i).getstart(),data.get(i).getnode(),data.get(i).getcoordstart());
                float tentative_g = currentnode.getg()+data.get(i).getcost();
                if((contains(successor, closedlist)||contains(reversesuccessor, closedlist))&&(tentative_g >=successor.getg()))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!(contains(successor, openlist))|| (tentative_g < successor.getg()))
                {
                    successor.setpredessor(currentnode.getnodenumber());
                    successor.setg(tentative_g);
                    successor.seth(manhattendistance(successor, dest));
                    successor.setf(successor.getg()+manhattendistance(successor, dest));
                    if(!contains(successor, openlist))
                    {
                        openlist.offer(successor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ArrayList<NodeD> ret = null;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: To paste a code would be useful and nice.

Comment: Concerning performance: First, Consider adding items in the openList to a `Set` called `openSet`, as well. You can quickly check if an item is in the openList by invoking `openSet.contains(node)`. Just be sure to also remove the item from the openSet when it's closed. Second, consider using an alternative openList: I saw a 10x speed improvement in my own A* algorithm using a `FibonnacciHeap` over Java's `PriorityQueue<E>`.

Answer (score 2):

The heuristic in A* must be [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) - that is, it must never overestimate the cost of moving between two nodes.

In your example, the cost between `[2,4]` and `[4,2]` is 3, but Manhatten distance is 4.  Thus, it's nonadmissible, and won't work for you as a heuristic.

> Do I have to delete the nodes in my openlist?

Er, yes, otherwise your `while` loop will never complete.  The removal is even explicitly stated in the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode)

Comment: Okay, but what I have to use as heuristics? Or is my code correct, but the example is chosen with worst case costs? My while loop is ending. It removes by executing openlist.poll(); the element with the lowest f value from the list.

Comment: Is it better to use the Euclidean Distance to calculate the heuristics?

Comment: @IrgendwPointer: That depends on what the actual problem in - in some cases, there is no good heuristic.  It **must** be admissible to return the shortest path *(and it would be best if it were [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) as well)*.  From your example, it doesn't look like Euclidean Distance would work either, since `[4,4]` and `[4,6]` are only distance 1 apart.

Comment: I use now the euclidean distance, which is quiet better than the Manhattan distance. But there still a lot of unnecessary nodes in my openlist. But my running time is 62ms for this short example. But I gues it is still too high, because my Dijkstra needs only 14ms. So something is still wrong in my algorithm but I don't know what.